# Compare two ArrayList<String>(); and delete the different elements

Tags: java, arraylist

i wanted to compare two ArrayList arrays and delete the different elements.

```
List<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> al2 = new ArrayList<String>();

al1.add("222");

al2.add("222");
al2.add("333");

System.out.println(al1);
System.out.println(al2);
```

The output of println is:

```
[222]
[222, 333]
```

I want to remove the 333 in the second array because it is not in the first one how can i achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by writing the code that does that. what have you tried so far?

Comment: `al2.retainAll(al1);`

Comment: You are expected to do *serious* prior posting questions. What makes you think that you are the *first* person on wondering how to do things like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `java.util.List.retainAll(Collection<?>)`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   List<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
   List<String> al2 = new ArrayList<String>();

   al1.add("222");

   al2.add("222");
   al2.add("333");

   al1.retainAll(al2);
   al2.retainAll(al1); // See Stultuske's comment.
   System.out.println(al1);
   System.out.println(al2);
}
```

Comment: and what are you forgetting in this example?

Comment: @Stultuske, tell me :)

Comment: al2.retainAll(al1); ;) for all we know, the extra variable in a next run is in al2, so you need to go retainAll on both

Comment: Thank you very much Marteng & Stultuske.. thought that it would be harder .